# I can't create a new instance of a ClassMirror by calling the defaullt constructor

Tags: oop, dart, reflection

I have two classes

```dart
class ESVAPI extends BibleProvider {
  ESVAPI() : super('esvapi', true, {'esv'});

 ...methods
}
```

```dart
abstract class BibleProvider {
  ...fields

  BibleProvider(this.name, this._requiresKey, this._versions) {
    Bible.addProvider(this, _versions.toList());
  }
}
```

I intend to have multiple classes extend the abstract class, so I want to create a method that creates an instances of each of `BibleProvider`'s subclasses, I created one here:

```dart
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(BibleProvider);
  List<DeclarationMirror> subClassMirrors = currentMirrorSystem()
      .libraries
      .values
      .expand((lib) => lib.declarations.values)
      .where((lib) {
    return lib is ClassMirror &&
        lib.isSubclassOf(classMirror) &&
        lib != classMirror;
  }).toList();
  DeclarationMirror subClassDec = subClassMirrors[0];
  ClassMirror ESVCLASS = reflectClass(subClassDec.runtimeType);
  var esvObj = ESVCLASS.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []);
```

But on `ESVCLASS.newInstance` I receive this exception:

```
No constructor '_ClassMirror' declared in class '_ClassMirror'
```

I'm thinking that this may have to do with how I call the superclass in the Constructor with "hard coded" values. If this is the case, is there a way to call the subclass' constructor and have it call the super constructor? I'm not entirely sure. Anyone familiar with reflections know what may be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last three lines to:

```dart
  ClassMirror subClassDec = subClassMirrors[0] as ClassMirror;
  var esvObj = subClassDec.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []);
  ...
  print(esvObj.reflectee.runtimeType); // ESVAPI
```

You are reflecting on something that is already a *mirror*, so your `ESVCLASS` becomes the class mirror of the class `_ClassMirror` itself, not the subclass of `BibleProvider` you found above.
Just use the `subClassDec` class mirror directly.

Comment: Oh ok, is using the `as` operator the same as casting? I decided not to use reflections in the program since I heard it could be very expensive, this will be helpful if I switch back, thank you!

Comment: The `as` operator is the cast operator in Dart, so it's definitely the same as casting.